# Angular Ui-Grid scroll not work in RTL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, right-to-left

when the grid has scroll in RTL and in Google Chrome there is issues:

- when you scroll vertically rows disappears
- when you scroll horizontally headers stick to left and columns scroll

but there is not a problem in Firefox

also column menu position is false (both Chrome and Firefox)
I checked it in version 4.0.4

you can check it in tutorial: [RTL Support](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/120_RTL)

Comment: seems new chrome versions have this issue, I saw this after early upgrades of chrome

Answer (score 0):

chrome 58 bug for scroll calculation:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=720227
change that caused the bug:
https://codereview.chromium.org/2716583002

as temporary solution for chrome 58 bug, put this hack after line 11562 of ui-grid.js

```
    //chrome 58 bug resolve
    var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
    if (isChrome) {
        type = "dafault";
    }
```